# React newbie - how to statically serve app (after build)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've created a *create_new_app* and ran `npm run build` -- my understanding was that this app is configured to package the js into a statically servable set of html + js + css files.

I opened the `index.html` located in the build folder on a browser, and found that the components are not rendering as they would if I ran `npm start`

This suggests that my understanding was incorrect. Can someone please help with what I'm missing here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Comment: Might be that your browser is blocking some JavaScript features for security reasons when accessing a html file locally, rather than through a server (which npm start provides). You'd need a HTTP server like Apache or nginx.

Answer (score 2):

You have to serve `build` folder.

First you have to install serve package:

```
npm install -g serve
```

then:

```
serve -s build
```

What is happening the js files built from react render html from your react code including component, so opening `index.html` will not render your components and react code.

This is client side rendering and it means what user see at end is render in client with final js files.

Comment: Thanks! I saw these two commands after running the `build` command. However, the reason I was trying to do that was to see if I can copy all the contents of the `build/` folder into my webserver which is currently serving simple html files. 

I was trying to introduce react components into this existing website.

I looked at the "add react to a website" section in the docs, but that was not for production JSX as I understand (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: As you can see in `index.html` there are some script, react need them. Also root tag, here is `div` with `id="app"` needed.